# Scala apply filter based on a flag

Tags: scala, collections, filter

To apply a filter only when a flag is set to true, My current solution looks like this:

```
val list = List(5,17,25,80)
val checkAge = false
val ageCheckedList = list.filter(i => i>18)
```

The idea is that if checkAge is set to true, filter should be applied, but if checkAge is false, do not perform the filtering.

What's a concise way of expressing this? The best I've come up with is this:

```
ageCheckedList = list.filterNot(i => checkAge && i <= 18)
```

which is very confusing to read to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is perfectly fine. You can invert the logic and that makes it a little more readable perhaps.

```
list.filter(i => !checkAge || i <= 18)
```

This basically says either we aren't checking age or the age is in the range.

Answer (score 0):

The following might express your intent more clearly:

```
val ageCheckedList = if (checkAge) list.filter(_ > 18) else list
```